# Definition of power series in $m$ indeterminates over a ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, formal-power-series

> Let $R$ be a non-trivial ring with unity and $m\in\mathbf{N}^*$. Set
> $X:=(X_1,\ldots,X_m)$. For $\alpha\in\mathbf{N}^{[1,m]}$, let
> $X^\alpha$ denote the formal power series in $m$ indeterminates over $R$
> such that $X^\alpha_\alpha=1$ and $X^\alpha_\beta=0$ for
> $\alpha\ne\beta$ ($\beta\in\mathbf{N}^{[1,m]}).$

What is the point of writing "$X:=(X_1,\ldots,X_m)$"? What set is $(X_1,\ldots, X_m)$ a member of? In an earlier section, the author defines $X$ as the formal power series in $1$ indeterminate for which $X_1=1$ and $X_n=0$ for $n\ne 1$. Are the $X_i$ values of that same power series $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.
You have to understand $X_1, \dots X_m$  are just shortcuts for these series with coefficients indexed by $\mathbf N^m$:
\begin{align}
X_1&=\bigl(0,1_{(1,0,0,\dots,0)}, 0, 0,0,\dots \bigr) \\
X_2&=\bigl(0,1_{(0,1,0,\dots,0)}, 0, 0,0,\dots \bigr) \\
&\enspace\vdots \\
X_m &=\bigl(0,1_{(0,0,0,\dots,1)}, 0, 0,0,\dots \bigr) 
\end{align}
and it can be shown that with Cauchy product and addition term by term, any series $(a_\underline \alpha)$, where $\underline\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_m)$, can be written explicitly as
$$\sum_{\underline\alpha\in\mathbf N^m}c_{\underline\alpha}\underline X^{\underline\alpha}=\mkern-24mu\sum_{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_m)\in\mathbf N^m}\mkern-6muc_{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_m)} X_1^{\alpha_1} X_2^{\alpha_2}\dotsm  X_m^{\alpha_m}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, if, for $1\leq i\leq m$, we denote by $\gamma_i$ the mapping from $[1,m]$ to $R$ such that $\gamma_i(i)=1$ and $\gamma_i(j)=0$ for $i\ne j$, then $X_i(\gamma_i)=1$ and $X_i(\alpha)=0$ for $\alpha\ne\gamma_i$. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, in a sense, $X_i$  is another notation for $\gamma_i$.

Comment: I see. I guess what I wanted to clarify is this. For $1\leq i\leq m$, $X_i$ is a mapping from $\mathbf{N}^m$ to $R$ for which $X_i(\gamma_i)=1$ and $X_i(\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha\ne\gamma_i\in\mathbf{N}^m$. So for each $1\leq i\leq m$, $X_i\in R^{\mathbf{N}^m}$ whereas $\gamma_i\in\mathbf{N}^m$. Is this a correct summary? Is this how I can define the $X_i$'s formally?

Comment: Yes. I believe it's the way Bourbaki does it. You may even add that $X_i\in R]{(\mathbf N^m)}$ (so that $R[X_1,\dots,X_m]\subset R[[X_1,\dots, X_m]]$).